# Use matched group to replace an string using preg_replace in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Having the following text:

```
$text = 'sometext bla bla <img src="images/aaa.png" border="0"> other text blabla'
```

The following regex matches all the  tag and the matched group #1 takes the url itself (`images/aaa.png`)

```
`\<img.+src\=(?:\"|\')(.+?)(?:\"|\')(?:.+?)\>`
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BWeKMX/1

How can I replace the matched url (`images/aaa.png`) and replace it to get something as follows?

```
$desiredSolution = 'sometext bla bla #_BLOCK_#IMG:images/aaa.png#_BLOCK_# other text blabla'
```

`preg_replace` would be the first idea, but I dont know how to put the matched group 1 there.

```
preg_replace('/\<img.+src\=(?:\"|\')(.+?)(?:\"|\')(?:.+?)\>/', "#_BLOCK_#IMG:" . I_NEED_TO_PUT_HERE_THE_MATCHED_GROUP_1 . "#_BLOCK_#, $text);
```

Any help? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The `$text` can contain more than one image.

Comment: You do _not_ want to replace the URL, but instead replace the image tag and _keep_ the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of the `preg_replace()` function answers your question: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Take a look at this simplified example:

```
<?php
var_dump(
  preg_replace(
    '|\<img.+src\=(?:")(.+?)(?:")(?:.+?)\>|',
    '#_BLOCK_#IMG:\\1#_BLOCK_#',
    'sometext bla bla <img src="images/aaa.png" border="0"> other text blabla'
  )
);
```

The output is:

```
string(71) "sometext bla bla #_BLOCK_#IMG:images/aaa.png#_BLOCK_# other text blabla"
```

This also works for multiple such image tags, the function will replace *all* occurrences, as documented:

```
<?php
var_dump(
  preg_replace(
    '|\<img.+src\=(?:")(.+?)(?:")(?:.+?)\>|',
    '#_BLOCK_#IMG:\\1#_BLOCK_#',
    <<<EOT
sometext bla
bla <img src="images/aaa.png" border="0"> other text
bla
bla <img src="images/bbb.png" border="0"> and going on with
further text
EOT
  )
);
```

The output of that obvious is:

```
string(143) "sometext bla
bla #_BLOCK_#IMG:images/aaa.png#_BLOCK_# other text
bla
bla #_BLOCK_#IMG:images/bbb.png#_BLOCK_# and going on with
further text"
```